# Lombok @slf4j not logging

Tags: spring, log4j, slf4j, lombok

I have a Spring application that uses @slf4j annotation from Lombok, but everything I log with it is not shown in the console.

My application includes the following library
slf4j-api-1.7.21
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21
lombok-1.16.10

Everything I log is being passed to NOPLogger (No Operation logger) that does exactly what it's supposed to do... nothing!

Do I need to configure a factory somewhere in order to use a logger that will actually log something?

Answer (score 12):

I figured, adding slf4j-api is not enough, you also need a proper implementation of the APi.

Adding this will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are importing @slf4j with Lombok, then you need 3 dependencies in your pom.xml file.

As @pmartin8 indicated, you need to add `slf4j-simple`, but all three required dependencies will look like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```